# method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for arguments (ArrayList<Product>, CustomProductComparator)

Tags: java, collections, comparator, custom-sort

Product with fields (id, productName, categoryName, etc).After making Arraylist of product and Populating it with Values like

```
 ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>(Arrays.asList(
                new DefaultProduct(1, "Hardwood Oak Suffolk Internal Door", "Doors", 109.99),
                new DefaultProduct(2, "Oregon Cottage Interior Oak Door", "Doors", 179.99),
                new DefaultProduct(3, "Oregon Cottage Horizontal Interior White Oak Door", "Doors", 189.99),
```

then sorting the ArrayList with code below

```
Collections.sort(products, new CustomProductComparator());
```

Eclipe giving erorr like
`The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Product>, CustomProductComparator)`
My custom Product comparator as below

```
public class CustomProductComparator implements Comparator<Product>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Product lhs, Product rhs) {
        //1 swap
        //-1 not swap
        
        
        int val = lhs.getCategoryName().compareTo(rhs.getCategoryName());
        if(val == 0) {
            if(lhs.getPrice() == rhs.getPrice()) {
                return lhs.getProductName().compareTo(rhs.getProductName());
            }
            else if (lhs.getPrice() < rhs.getPrice()) {
                return -1;
            }
            else {
                return 1;
            }
            
        }
        else {
            return val;
        }
    }
    
}
```

```
public interface Product {

    int getId();

    String getProductName();
    
    String getCategoryName();
    
    double getPrice();

}


public class DefaultProduct implements Product {
    
    private int id;
    private String productName;
    private String categoryName;
    private double price;

    public DefaultProduct() {
    }
    
    public DefaultProduct(int id, String productName, String categoryName, double price) {
        this.id = id;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product id=" + id + ", product name=" + productName
                + ", category name=" + categoryName + ", price=" + price;
    }

    @Override
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getProductName() {
        return this.productName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getCategoryName() {
        
        return this.categoryName;
    }

    @Override
    public double getPrice() {
        
        return this.price;
    }

    
}
```

I tried `Collections.sort(products, new CustomProductComparator());`
I was expecting sorting would work according to my customProductComparator
But actual resulted was error on line when applying "sort(products, new CustomProductComparator()"
with giving error like `The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Product>, CustomProductComparator)`

Comment: It works for me. Does your DefaultProduct extend Product?

Comment: Why did you not provide the classes `Product` and `DefaultProduct` with configured getters? Please do so.

Comment: Among the more likely possibilities are: (1) the version of `CustomProductComparator` being referenced by the compiler is not consistent with the source code presented in the question, and (2) the `Product` for which `CustomProductComparator` is a comparator is not the same `Product` that parameterizes your list.

Comment: @f1sh DefaultProduct implements Product

Comment: @WJS Edited with code details. Now can you please review it

Comment: @JohnBollinger the 1)  Possibility worked for me. The Eclipse took wrong CustomProductComparator. After seeing import path properly, I changed to my CustomProductComparator and it worked as intended. Thanks JohnBolliger
And others

Comment: @Jaykumar Your code works fine as written.  You may want to check out the `Comparator interface` for some helpful methods.  Try this as a comparator. 
 `Comparator<Product> custom = Comparator.comparing(Product::getCategoryName).thenComparing(Product::getPrice).thenComparing(Product::getProductName);`  `thenComparing` will run if the previous comparator returns 0 (i.e. the values are equal).

Comment: @WJS thanks for such a new and method for comparing

Comment: While the implementation code of the comparator is correct, the comments are misleading. The return values of the `compare` method do *not* mean “swap” or “not swap”. When you check [the contract of the method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#compare(T,T)) you’ll notice that the word “swap” does not appear in it at all.

Answer (score 0):

The version of `CustomProductComparator` being referenced by the compiler is not consistent with the source code presented in the question.

> Actually **Eclipse** Automatically `Import` the Wrong
> `CustomProductComparator` that is why such an error comes in my case.

Kindly check Above situation.

The comments swap (Positive value, +1) and not Swap(Negative, -1, 0) is just for my understanding to easier learn comparator. Thanks @John Bollinger for answer.